# Apply animateColor to multiple SVG elements

Tags: animation, svg

Is there any way to define a color animation for multiple elements at once? I tried adding the `animateColor` to a `g` element, but that didn't work. I could use Javascript to add an `animateColor` to each element individually, but I'd prefer to do it all in the static SVG data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use `animate` instead of `animateColor`.  Firefox, at least, doesn't implement `animateColor` at the moment and it is being deprecated in SVG 1.1 Second Edition.  Using `animate` for animating fill and stroke works just fine.  For example:

```
<g>
  <animate attributeName="fill" from="black" to="red" dur="5s"/>
  <rect width="100" height="100"/>
  <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="50"/>
</g>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Firefox doesn't seem to support *any* kind of SVG animation, but it works in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Firefox 4 supports SVG animation.

Comment: Well, when I say that Firefox doesn't support something, I mean that the latest stable release doesn't support it.

Comment: Another thing I just noticed (using Chrome): putting animateColor into the g does work as expected - as long as the elements don't already have a 'fill' property defined. When animateColor is inside a rect tag, it overrides the rect's fill property. (The animate tag behaves the same way.) So this might be a bug in WebKit.

Comment: Luckily you'll only need to wait a few more days until the latest stable Firefox release supports animation. :-)

That the fill on the 'g' doesn't override the fill specified on the child 'rect' is correct behaviour, BTW.  It's the same as if you had <g fill="red"><rect fill="black"/></g>.