# SVG not animating when dynamically added

Tags: javascript, svg

If I add SVG dynamically it won't animate on certain browsers.  It took me a while to track down the problem.  Here is the simplest example I could make illustrating the problem.

[my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pECn/)

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "<svg width='100' height='100'><circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='50' fill='red'><animateColor id='a1' attributeName='fill' values='blue;green;yellow;orange;red;blue' dur='5s' repeatCount='indefinite' /></circle></svg>";
}, 0);
```

It works on Chrome and Safari 6.1 Seed, but not Safari 6.0 or <s>Firefox</s>.

EDIT: Same problem with Safari on iOS 6 but it does work with Safari on iOS 7 Beta.

Comment: Firecfox dosent support SVG
Refer this:

[SVG Not Supported][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371365/apply-animatecolor-to-multiple-svg-elements

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I didn't know that.  I'm still interested to know though how to fix this in Safari 6.0.

Comment: @AbhishekJain What are you talking about? As stated in the accepted answer to the question you yourself linked, Firefox supports SVG just fine, it's the `animateColor` property specifically that it doesn't support, and that's not needed anyway because `animate` does it just fine.

Comment: @BerryBlue Does it animate normally in Safari 6.0 when you add the SVG and elements statically? If so, you might want to try building the dynamic element dynamically; take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/5pECn/4/ and see if it works any differently.

Comment: Yes, it animates normally when added statically just not when added dynamically.  It does work in your example but I need to do it just by setting the innerHTML not building it dynamically.